# Importance of keystore certificate for SAML SSO

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, saml, x509certificate, spring-saml

I am new to certificates and keystores.

What is the importance & working of keystores, and certificates for SAML SSO (in context of Spring boot SAML SSO)?

I see `.jks`, `.pem`, `.cer`, `.der`, etc. in use. What are these?

Answer (score 5):

**What is the importance & working of KeyStore, and certificates for SAML SSO (in context of Spring boot SAML SSO)?**

- These are used for Security implications for signing SAML assertions,
  SAML protocol request and response.
- Certificates in SAML SSO will be used to digitally sign the SAML
  assertion/request/response and KeyStore is the persistent storage to
  store the keys/certificates.
- An assertion signed by the asserting party supports assertion
  integrity, authentication of the asserting party to a SAML relying
  party, and, if the signature is based on the SAML authority’s
  public-private key pair, non-repudiation of origin.
- A SAML protocol request or response message signed by the message
  originator supports message integrity, authentication of message
  origin to a destination, and, if the signature is based on the
  originator's public-private key pair, non-repudiation of origin.
- Certificates are also used for secure channel establishment
  (SSL/TLS).

**What are the .jks, .pem, .cer, .der, etc.?**

- .jks is extension to JAVA's proprietary KeyStore (JKS) format. JKS is
  the database format for both the private key, and the associated
  certificate or certificate chain. Till JAVA 8, by default, as
  specified in the java.security file, keytool uses JKS as the format
  of the key and certificate databases (KeyStore and TrustStores).
  Since JAVA 9 the default KeyStore format has been changed to
  PKCS12(extension .pkcs).

> .pem, .cer, .der are the certificate/key types/extensions:

- .PEM : The PEM extension is used for different types of X.509v3 files
  which contain ASCII (Base64) armored data prefixed with a “—– BEGIN
  …” line.
- .DER : The DER extension is used for binary DER encoded certificates.
  These files may also bear the CER or the CRT extension.   Proper
  English usage would be “I have a DER encoded certificate” not “I have
  a DER certificate”.
- .CRT : The CRT extension is used for certificates. The certificates
  may be encoded as binary DER or as ASCII PEM. The CER and CRT
  extensions are nearly synonymous.  Most common among *nix systems.
- CER : alternate form of .crt (Microsoft Convention) You can use MS to
  convert .crt to .cer (.both DER encoded .cer, or base64[PEM] encoded
  .cer)  The .cer file extension is also recognized by IE as a command
  to run a MS cryptoAPI command (specifically rundll32.exe
  cryptext.dll,CryptExtOpenCER) which displays a dialogue for importing
  and/or viewing certificate contents.
- .KEY : The KEY extension is used both for public and private PKCS#8
  keys. The keys may be encoded as binary DER or as ASCII PEM.